# make socket.io send emit message to only one client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have read other answers but they are not solving my problem.
The problem is I making an online multiplayer chess game. First Say I have a list of participants and 10 are present in a list. I want admin to send request to any user in the list. SO by using `Socket.io with nodejs` I emit an event from my `react` client side. But I want only that particular user to get the request. I am failing here. As when i apply `to()` in my `socket` Next line get printed but the socket on client does not get call. And if in the same condition I remove `to()` from my emit and broadcast it simply, The client side `socket.on` fires immediatly.

client

```
  useEffect(() => {
        console.log("this effect run")
        socket.on('joinRequestRecieved', ({ id, name, room }) => {
            
            console.log("req recieved from user ", id, name, room)
        })
    }, [])

    const sendJoinReqToThisUser = (userName, userId, roomID) => {
        socket.emit('sendJoinRequest', { userName, userId, roomID });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h3>Users In Room</h3>
            <ul style={style.listStyle}>
                {
                    (participants.s) && participants.s.map(user => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <li key={user.id}>{user.name} <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => sendJoinReqToThisUser(user.name, user.id, user.room)} style={style.buttonStyle}>Request</button></li>
                                <hr></hr>
                            </>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export default ParticipantsList
```

NodeJs

```
    socket.on('sendJoinRequest', async ({ userName, userId, roomID }) => {
        console.log("In send Join Request", userName, userId, roomID , socket.id );
        let u = use.find(user => user.name == userName);
       await socket.broadcast.to(u.id).emit('joinRequestRecieved', {
            id: userId,
            name: userName,
            room: roomID
        });
        console.log("I am done")
    })


const getUsersInRoom = (room) => users.filter((user) => user.room === room);
const getUsersInRoom = (room) => users.filter((user) => user.room === room);
```

See this bash result . Line next to socket get executed but i don't see any update on client
[image]

Answer (score 0):

socket.emit('message')
will simply return a message to the sender

socket.to(socketId).emit('message')
accepts a socket id and will message a single client

socket.brodcast.to(roomName).emit('message')
accepts a room name and emits a message to all clients who have joined that room except the one that sent the request

io.in(roomName).emit('message')
accepts a room name and sends a message to everyone in the room including the client who sent the request

io.to(socketId).emit('message')
accepts a socket id and will send a message to a single client

[I personally found the socket.io cheatsheet really useful when learning all these](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/index.html)

**none of these accept an array** and your .filter function is currently returning an array so this won't send anything

I can't quite figure out which of the above scenarios you need but they all accept a single room name or socket id. none accept an array.

Comment: I get you. But the answer you have given is not relevant to this specific case. I already have 10 user and from the list I am requesting the user to join the game. By `joinrequest`. The thing is I don't want to other 9 to know that request has been sent to that client , only the client to whom it is send should recieve. I am getting clear id of the client and broadcasting it too but the client side is not receiving the 'joinRequestRecieved' emit.

Comment: Ah okay understood. I was confused because I couldn't see the code for getUsersInRoom. and I assumed it was returning an array as Users is pluralised.

Comment: No issue . I have updated few lines for the latest snippet.

Comment: Well now I'm not to sure I do understand because .filter is returning an array, none of the options accept an array. If you are just trying to return a message to the sender then socket.emit() is enough. see if any of the options I've given help.